# Retrieving element's attributes from xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<resultsPage status="ok">
      <results>
        <artist displayName="someName">
           <identifier eventsHref="somelink">
           </identifier>
           <identifier eventsHref="somelink">
           </identifier>

        </artist> 
        <artist displayName="someName">
           <identifier eventsHref="someName">
           </identifier>
        </artist> 
        <artist someattributes>
        </artist> 
      </results>
</resultsPage>
```

So i have this xml file.So the thing i want to do is firstly retrieve and display every artist's "displayName" and then for each artist element all the identifier's "eventsHref".
This is the code in javascript i wrote so i can take each displayName from artist element.

```
x=xmlDoc.documentElement;
events=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("artist");
for (i=0;i<events.length;i++)
{
    event=events[i].getAttribute("displayName");

    document.write(event+"<br>");       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery for that here is how: 
I assume that your javascript file is reading an external xml document therefore you can do a $.ajax to get the content of the file:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'pathtoTheFile.xml',
        async: false, 
        dataType: 'xml', 
        success: function(data){
            getData(data);
        }, 
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

once you have the xml data call the function getData:

```
  function getData(data){

     var DisplayNameArray = []; 
     var eventsHrefArray = [];  

     $(data).find('artist').each(function(){
         DisplayNameArray.push($(this).attr('displayName'));

         $(this).find('identifier').each(function(){
             eventsHrefArray.push($(this).attr('eventsHref'));
         })
     }); 

     console.log(DisplayNameArray); 
     console.log(eventsHrefArray); 

 }
```

The function is storing the values of  'displayName' in DisplayNameArray and the values of 'eventsHref' in eventsHrefArray. Then you can do whatever you want with the data including adding it to your page.

For the xml example you gave the content of the arrays would be:

```
  console.log(DisplayNameArray);    
  >>["someName", "someName"] 
   console.log(eventsHrefArray);    
  >>["somelink", "somelink", "someName"]
```

PS: there is an error in your xml file at the end

EDIT: 
If you want to separate you data elements eventsHref based on the displayName it is as easy. However in this case you data elements cannot be stored within  an array I would rather use a java object (a JSON like structure).

```
    function getData(data){

     var myData = []; 
     var tmpData = {displayName: '', eventsHref: []}; //initialize a temporary object   

     $(data).find('artist').each(function(){
         tmpData.displayName = $(this).attr('displayName');

         $(this).find('identifier').each(function(){
             tmpData.eventsHref.push($(this).attr('eventsHref'));
         })


            myData.push(tmpData); 
            tmpData = {displayName: '', eventsHref: []};
     }); 

     //do something with the data here: 
     console.log(myData); 
 }
```

Now you can access each displayName this way:

```
  myData[0].displayName; //of course you will have to go through the array to print the list for instance.
```

And you can access the list of eventsHref related to that displayName this way:

```
  myData[0].eventsHref;
```

For the xml example you gave, printing the content of myData (after removing the error in the xml file) would give:

```
 [{"displayName":"someName","eventsHref":["somelink","somelink"]},{"displayName":"someName","eventsHref":["someName"]}];
```

hope this helps.

Comment: First of all thank you for your interest and your answer.My problem isn't just to get all eventsHref or artist's display name.Maybe i didn't explain it that good.The thing is that every artist element has a number of identifiers which is not the same with the other and not standard.
For example i need to take the first artist's displayName and the 2 identifier's eventsHref which is inside it and so on for it's artist.
The xml file i show you is just a part of a bigger one.

Comment: I need to seperate which identifier's evetsHref belongs to each artist's displayName.


PS :Sorry for my english.I try to explain that as good i can

Comment: well,the answer to you requirement is in the original code I posted for each displayName (artist) I go through all the possible eventsHref check the new update I put the data in java objects so that you get the link between artist and its identifiers.

Comment: This is exaclty what i was looking for!Thank you very much for your help.Works perfectly.

Comment: I am new to this site.Didn't know that sorry.